# Using the 'and' operator inside Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using Perl to read in a file line by line and `die` if a condition is met. The condition being that a line has to begin with any of the letters `AGCT` and the rest of the line can only contain the letters `AGCT`.

```
my $fasta = $ARGV[0];

open(FASTA, $fasta) || die("Couldn't read file $fasta\n");
local $/ = "\n>";
while (my $line = <>) {
  if ( $line =~ /^[AGCT]/ && /[AGCT]/ ) {
    die;
  }
}
close FASTA;
```

I know the syntax in the regexp is wrong, I have tried many variations but can't get it, any ideas?

Comment: You open `FASTA`, but then you do nothing with it. Your while loop reads from `ARGV` instead.

Comment: Ahh thankyou @melpomene.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your regular expression syntax is correct. Your Perl expression in the `if` condition is wrong.

```
if ( 
    $line =~ /^[AGCT]/   # this tests $line
    && /[AGCT]/          # this defaults to $_
) {
```

You need to use `$line =~ //` explicitly both times.

In addition, your second pattern does not do what you want. You are missing a `*$`, and it would make sense to include the beginning character, too. It should read

```
/^[AGCT][AGCT]*$/
```

As you can see, essentially you can just have one pattern and be done with it.

```
if ( $line =~ /^[AGCT]+$/ ) { ... }
```

You can shorten it even further by doing the opposite pattern and saying it shouldn't match.

```
if ( $line !~ /[^AGCT]/ ) { ... }
```

This is a bit confusing because of the double negation ( `!~` and `[^]` though.

In any case, you should `chomp` your input first. I would write your program like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# the \n removes the line number from die
open my $fh, '<', $fasta or die "Couldn't read file $fasta";

local $/ = "\n>";
while (my $line = <>) {
  chomp $line;
  die if $line =~ /[^AGCT]/;
}
```

That program will die if any of the lines contains something that is not `A`, `G`, `C` or `T`. I do believe that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: or `$line =~ /[^AGCT]/`

Comment: @choroba That's slightly different in that simbabque's regex allows a trailing newline whereas yours doesn't. Also, simbabque's regex doesn't accept empty strings.

Comment: @choroba and if you were going to do that, it might as well be `$line =~ y/AGCT//c`

Comment: `$line =~ /^[AGCT]+$/` is not the same as `$line !~ /[^AGCT]/`. The latter matches an empty string.

Comment: There's also the issue that `$line` might be terminated by `\n>`. It probably can even include newlines.

Comment: The program should really `chomp`, but I didn't include that.

Comment: @ysth `y///` performs a count, so it's always O(n) even if the first character of the string is not A/G/C/T.

Comment: @melpomene it's clear from the code here that the expectation is that it is; don't optimize for the unexpected